# Rundown on Jira Permissions

Tags: php, permissions, groups

I'm trying to setup Jira for some company projects, and also some personal projects, and I'm running into some confusion with the permissions.

Would someone running a Jira server be able to give me a basic rundown of the most efficient way to setup company projects (where a group of people will be working on the project), and a personal project (where only myself, and perhaps one other person will be working on the project)?

Any help on this, or a very basic "best practices" guide for Jira permissions would be extremely helpful.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

I am not administering Jira at my company, but I was involved in the initial setup, so some things here might be somewhat misnamed.

---

*Jira has groups*.  You can configure who is in each group, what groups are in what groups, etc. You can also integrate it with LDAP (Windows Active Directory).

*Jira has roles*.  Some examples: Administrators, Creators, Developers, Testers, Users.  These can be customized.  Depending what role a person has, they will be allowed to do different things with the project.  For example, if you are a Creator, you can create new issues; if a developer, you can work on issues; a tester can verify issues.  For each project, you can pick what users and what groups have the specific role.

---

So for example, lets say you had the following setup:

Users:

- Homer
- Marge
- Bart
- Lisa

Groups:

- QA Group: Bart, Lisa
- Manager Groups: Homer, Marge

Projects/Roles:

- Intellectual Work

  - Administrators: Managers Group
  - Developers: Marge, Lisa
  - Testers: QA Group
  - Users: All Users Group
- Physical Work

  - Administrators: Managers Group
  - Developers: Homer, Bart
  - Testers: QA Group
  - Users: All Users Group
- Parenting Work

  - Administrators: Homer, Marge

Everything I hope is fairly easy to follow.  As a note, neither Lisa or Bart will see the "Parenting Work" Project.